# Nuxt error : Unknown custom element

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, nuxt.js

I am using nuxt js. I am trying to install a vue package vue-zoom. Actually few more plugins.

```
{ src: '~/plugins/zoom', ssr: false },
```

Here I kept ssr false because it gives errors like document is not defined...

In my plugins/zoom.js file I have this

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import vZoom from 'vue-zoom'
Vue.use(vZoom);
```

Now when I am trying to use this plugin like this

```
<v-zoom :img="`/uploads/${displayImg}`" ></v-zoom>
```

It gives me the above error. 
Any reason or thought how can I use this plugin or similar in nuxt js?

I tried few more all gives similar errors.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error when having the `buildDir` set to my `functions/.nuxt` folder, which I was using for SSR via Firebase Functions. I was able to solve the issue by making sure neither `nuxt` nor `vue` was installed in the `node_modules` inside the functions folder.

Are you using a similar setup by chance?